# QTreeView selection clears text color

Tags: c++, qt, selection, qtreeview

I have subclassed `QTreeView` and made model subclassed from `QAbstractTableModel`and everything works fine. If something is being changed in QTreeView from code (not by user), then that row's text color becomes red. I have implemented this trough checking `Qt::TextColorRole` from `data()` function and returning `Qt::red`.

But if that particular row is being selected, then text color changes automatically to black (and background color to light green, which is normal). After deselecting that row everything is OK again. In debug mode I've seen that `data()` function returns true value for selected row (`Qt::red`).

Now how can I solve this problem, what may cause to this incorrect behaviour?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way of doing this trough a delegate. Here is the code

```
class TextColorDelegate: public QItemDelegate
{
public:
  explicit TextColorDelegate(QObject* parent = 0) : QItemDelegate(parent)
  { }

  void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const  
  {
    QStyleOptionViewItem ViewOption(option);

    QColor itemForegroundColor = index.data(Qt::ForegroundRole).value<QColor>();
    if (itemForegroundColor.isValid())
    {
      if (itemForegroundColor != option.palette.color(QPalette::WindowText))
        ViewOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, itemForegroundColor);

    }
    QItemDelegate::paint(painter, ViewOption, index);
 }
};
```

And for using delegate you should write something like this

```
pTable->setItemDelegate(new TextColorDelegate(this));
```

where `pTable`'s type is `QTableView*`;

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code keep your text color red?

```
QPalette p = view->palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, QColor(Qt::red));
view->setPalette(p);
```

Comment: Actually this changes highlighted text color like everytime, but I need to change a specific row's text color when it is being changed.